# Proper way to do map generation in java

Tags: java, jframe, maps

I was thinking about making a game with a map larger than the screen like most open world games. The question I run in to is when a player wants to move on the map how do I move the screen or how would I go about properly rendering new spots on the map. This is like any game such as Mario, awesome tanks 2, basically all tile map 2d games.

So formally my question is "How would I go about rendering new parts of a tile map".

Here is my exact situation:
I have a text file that contains a grid of numbers. Each number represents a texture and have their own properties. Now when I generate this I can create a panel and add all the tiles on to it and only show a 7x7 grid. Now as the player hits the keys the map should move as the player stays in the middle of the screen. Now the only way I can think to do this is to render all the tiles at once bigger than the frame itself that way only a 7x7 grid is showing at any given time and than change the x and y of the panel containing all the tiles. This seems really inefficient beings that it's rendering the entire map at the same time. So in conclusion when a player moves they should stay in the center of the screen and move the map in the background. And since the background is bigger what is the best way to do this.

Comment: Look for a 2D game engine to help you.